# Alternative to double imprecision in Dart

Tags: dart, math, precision

I made a calculator with Flutter, but I forgot to consider the problem with doubles. Is there any way to keep precision without using toStringAsFixed() with a low argument? I would like to keep at least 10 decimal points and 'perfect' precision. I'm using the Math_expressions package

Comment: Try take a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/decimal

Comment: "double imprecision", I like that.

Comment: Related: "[Towards an API for the real numbers](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3385412.3386037)" describes how precision problems were solved in the Android calculator -- which is anything but trivial.